# dlib installation on Windows 10

Tags: python, image-processing, dlib

I want to use `dlib` with python for image recognition. I have the python app running great with OpenCV on Windows 10, but when I want to install `dlib` from the `cmd` it gives me this following error :

```
error: Cannot find cmake, ensure it is installed and in the path. You
can install cmake using the instructions at https://cmake.org/install/
You can also specify its path with --cmake parameter.
```

What should I do?

[image: My command prompt error]

Comment: **edit** your question to include the actual error instead of just attaching a screenshot.  This will make it easier to answer your question and will make your question useful to others with similar problems as well.

Answer (score 94):

### <s>Install Dlib from .whl</s> (old, see next paragraph)

Dlib **19.7.0**

```
pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/da/06/bd3e241c4eb0a662914b3b4875fc52dd176a9db0d4a2c915ac2ad8800e9e/dlib-19.7.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl#md5=b7330a5b2d46420343fbed5df69e6a3f
```

You can test it, downloading an example from the site, for example [SVM_Binary_Classifier.py](http://dlib.net/svm_binary_classifier.py.html) and running it on your machine.

**Note**: if this message occurs you have to **build dlib from source**:

> dlib-19.7.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

---

### Install Dlib from source (If the solution above doesn't work)

### Windows

**Dlib > 19.7.0**

1. Download the CMake installer and install it: https://cmake.org/download/
2. Add CMake executable path to the Enviroment Variables:

   `set PATH="%PATH%;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin"`

   *note*: The path of the executable could be different from `C:\Program Files\CMake\bin`, just set the PATH accordingly.

   *note*: The path will be set temporarily, to make the change permanent you have to set it in the [“Advanced system settings” → “Environment Variables”](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10) tab.
3. Restart The Cmd or PowerShell window for changes to take effect.
4. Download the Dlib source(.tar.gz) from the Python Package Index : https://pypi.org/project/dlib/#files extract it and enter into the folder.
5. Check the Python version: `python -V`. This is my output: `Python 3.7.2` so I'm installing it for Python3.x and **not** for Python2.x

*note*: You can install it for both Python 2 and Python 3, if you have set different variables for different binaries i.e: `python2 -V`, `python3 -V`

*note*: You **may** need to open the PowerShell as admin before proceeding to step 6

---

6. Run the installation: `python setup.py install`

---

### **Linux**

**Dlib 19.17.0**

```
sudo apt-get install cmake

wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/05/57/e8a8caa3c89a27f80bc78da39c423e2553f482a3705adc619176a3a24b36/dlib-19.17.0.tar.gz

tar -xvzf dlib-19.17.0.tar.gz

cd dlib-19.17.0/

sudo python3 setup.py install
```

*note*: To install Dlib for Python 2.x use `python` instead of `python3` you can check your python version via `python -V`

Comment: dlib-19.7.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: but it should be supported :( `pip._internal.pep425tags.get_supported()` -> `(...) ('cp36', 'cp36m', 'win32') (...)` ... installing it from the source is such a pain, especially on Windows

Comment: Even if you have CMake installed, on windows you will have problems with the generator of CMake which is by default set to Nmake.

Comment: @FlashThunder were you trying to install it on a 32bit machine?

Comment: @MarcoD.G. no, 64

Comment: Thanks, but I need to add something obvious! In order to build this for Python, make sure you have C++ compiler on your system!

Comment: I am getting this

`  You must use Visual Studio to build a python extension on windows.  If you
  are getting this error it means you have not installed Visual C++.  Note
  that there are many flavors of Visual Studio, like Visual Studio for C#
  development.  You need to install Visual Studio for C++.`

is it necessary to install?

Comment: @FAHADSIDDIQUI, it is indeed needed. After installing I receive a new error: `No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found`

Comment: It's Aug 2023 and I had same issues and installing VS Tools didn't help. I had to finally install with the source code. I'm on Windows.

Answer (score 72):

Follow these steps:

- `pip install cmake`
- Install Visual Studio build tools from [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&rel=15#).
- In Visual Studio 2017 go to the Individual Components tab, Visual C++ Tools for
  Cmake, and check the checkbox under the "Compilers, build tools and runtimes" section.
- `pip install dlib`

Comment: i tried most of the ways here and dlib still doesn't seems to work

Comment: yes it works, to confirm, if your message is of kind "is not a supported on this platform", so be sure to install Visual C++ Tools for Cmake from visual studio installer ==>  Individual Components tab

Comment: when following these steps, I run into a new error `No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.`

Comment: Wooow it's like 5GB of installation which is a bit frustrating

Comment: this works well! even with that kind of installation, I guess it's because the algo is that big

Answer (score 17):

Effective till now(2020).

```
pip install cmake
conda install -c conda-forge dlib
```

Comment: via conda , which python version u used for this ??

Comment: Works for me on Python 3.12. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

If you are using ***Anaconda Prompt*** (recommended),

```
conda install -c conda-forge dlib
```

***Or you can use the approach mentioned below:***

After spending a lot of time, this comment gave me the right result.
https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/issues/802#issuecomment-544232494

1. Download Python 3.6.8 and install, make sure you add it to PATH.
2. Install NumPy, scipy, matplotlib and pandas in your pc/laptop with this command in command prompt:-

   pip install numpy

   pip install scipy

   pip install matplotlib

   pip install pandas
3. Go to https://pypi.org/project/wheel/#files and right-click on filename wheel-0.33.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (21.6 kB) and copy link address. Then go to your pc/laptop, open command prompt and write this command "python -m pip install" after this command space first then paste the link copied. After installing successful go to the next step.
4. Then go to this link, https://pypi.org/simple/dlib/ and right-click on filename "dlib-19.8.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl" then copy link address. Then open command prompt and do the same as step 2 which is, write this command "python -m pip install" after this command space first then paste the link copied. then the dlib will be installed successfully.
5. After that, type python and enter, then type import dlib to check dlib is installed perfectly. you can proceed to install face recognition.py which suite for python 3.6.

[image: This is how it will be after dlib and face recognition installed.]

Answer (score 6):

As you can see many answers above, But i would like to post a quick solution which works for sure in Anaconda3. I haven't chosen Visual Studio as it consumes lot of memory.

Please follow the below steps.

```
Step 1:
Install windows cmake.msi and configure environment variable
```

```
Step 2:
Create a conda environment, and install cmake using the below command.
pip install cmake
```

```
Step 3:
conda install -c conda-forge dlib
```

Note you can find few other dlib packages, but the above one will works perfectly with this procedure.

dlib will be successfully installed.

Comment: this is the only one which worked for me, when running step 3 from an Administrator rights Anaconda powershell terminal

Answer (score 5):

You need to install [Cmake](https://cmake.org/download/).

dlib is an c++ libary with python bindings. It needs to be builded first. My guess is this will happen automatically once you have installed Cmake

Comment: I have installed Cmake, could you please tell me how to make it work and with cmake what should i put in "Where is the source code?" and "Where to build the binaries?"

Comment: @Drill just reinvoke pip install dlib.

Comment: @Drill make sure cmake is in your path variable

Comment: I tried the same and tried to invoke pip install dlib. it is throwing error "error MSB4
019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk."  There is no "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" in my system. Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: @AbhinavVaidya8 I am sorry, but I have no idea how to resolve this.

Comment: Did the trick for me. Installing cmake via pip and visual was not enough.

Answer (score 4):

So basically I have been searching the solution for two days.
I tried everything

- Installing Cmake
- Adding path
- installing dlib from the links mentioned in the answers
- Installing ## Heading ## numpy, scipy, matplotlib, pandas
- etc etc etc

BUT THE ONLY SOLUTION THAT WORKED WAS
INSTALLING **MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO C++**

After installing MS VS C++ I ran command `pip install dlib` and it is working like a charm.
BEST OF LUCK

Link to download Visual Studio C++

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-for-downloading-visual-studio-for-cplusplus/?sku=Community&rel=16&rid=30005

Comment: Thank you Bilal! It's unbelievable how every single answer around seems to forget that CMake is NOT a compiler, and that people might not have any C++ compiler installed at all, particularly Python devs. I'm installing from scratch on a NUC and I'm just struggling on what exactly are the absolute minimum requirements to compile DLib. I'm installing like 16GB of VS C++ crap only to generate a 8MB pyc. Why is DLib not distributed compiled, like everything else, anyway?

Answer (score 1):

You have to install cmake as the error tells you.

you can follow this instructions https://www.learnopencv.com/install-dlib-on-windows/

or directly install cmake from here https://cmake.org/download/

Once cmake is installed pip install dlib should work.

I had vstudio building tools installed whe I did my test.

Answer (score 1):

Choose dlib .whl file according to your installed python version.
For example if installed python version is 3.6.7 , 64bit system or if python is 3.5.0  32 bit
then choose dlib-19.5.1-**cp36**-cp36m-win_**amd64**.whl and dlib-18.17.100-**cp35**-none-**win32**.whl respectively.

Bolded text says the python supporting version.

Download wheel file from [here](https://pypi.org/simple/dlib/) or copy the link address

```
pip install dlib-19.5.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

for above method .whl file shoud be in the working directory

or

Below link for python3.6 supporting dlib link, for python 3.5 u can replace with dlib 35.whl link

```
pip install https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/24/ea/81e4fc5b978277899b1c1a63ff358f1f645f9369e59d9b5d9cc1d57c007c/dlib-19.5.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl#sha256=7739535b76eb40cbcf49ba98d894894d06ee0b6e8f18a25fef2ab302fd5401c7
```

Answer (score 1):

1.use python 3.6.9 version

2.first install cmake.

```
conda install -c anaconda cmake
```

3. use these command to install dlib

`pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/da/06/bd3e241c4eb0a662914b3b4875fc52dd176a9db0d4a2c915ac2ad8800e9e/dlib-19.7.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl#md5=b7330a5b2d46420343fbed5df69e6a3f`

Comment: This is the most simple way of doing it, on Windows. All u need to do is revert back to Python `3.6.x` and do `pip install cmake` and then `pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/da/06/bd3e241c4eb0a662914b3b4875fc52dd176a9db0d4a2c915ac2ad8800e9e/dlib-19.7.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl#md5=b7330a5b2d46420343fbed5df69e6a3f`. I have used just this in my face detection system, for easy install. Check out at https://github.com/UBISOFT-1/Project_Exodus.git

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick update on what has worked for me (two years later). Davis King has provided two ways to add the latest python dlib (19.17.0) to any python environment in Windows 10 for me. Note, I run several Linux configs in Oracle VirtualBox but Windows 10 is my native OS which has access to the Nvidia GPU so i need an install on Windows 10. (Cannot access the GPU - easily - through VirtualBox).

First - the easiest:

```
pip install dlib
```

and the website link: https://pypi.org/project/dlib/

And then it can be easily be build from sources. Download from https://pypi.org/simple/dlib/ and follow instructions on http://dlib.net/compile.html.

Also, just found another way to access with Visual Studio 2019 (or 2017). Use vcpkg - see link https://vcpkg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

I built dlib 19.17 on Windows 10 with CMake and it worked fine but then I found vcpkg and now the dlib libraries are integral to the Visual Studio. I no longer need to add all the external links to C++ and the linker.The version in vcpkg is currently 19.16-1 and it is built with full CUDA support.

Hope this helps others..

Answer (score 0):

You can use *vcpkg* to install *dlib*.

If you don't have *vcpkg*, you can get it [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg) (Read Quick Start)

After you got vcpkg, run:

```
vcpkg install dlib:x64-windows
```

Answer (score 0):

I have recently installed dlib on python 3.7.
First I have installed cmake from anaconda navigator `(cmake version 3.14.0)`
Next i installed visual studio 2019 and installed **Desktop development with C++** .
Then I do `pip install dlib` and now its working

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers worked for me. This is what worked
Assuming you have anaconda python 3.7 installed

1) Dowload and install cmake(make sure to check the option to add cmake to system path during installation to avoid manually doing later) 
Download from this link [cmake download](https://cmake.org/download/)

2) `conda install -c conda-forge dlib`

Answer (score 0):

It is basically a two-step process:

1. install cmap

```
pip install cmap
```

2. install dlib

```
pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/da/06/bd3e241c4eb0a662914b3b4875fc52dd176a9db0d4a2c915ac2ad8800e9e/dlib-19.7.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl#md5=b7330a5b2d46420343fbed5df69e6a3f
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to install dlib on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2019, then first perform:

```
pip install cmake
```

And set it in the environment variable. After that, make sure that you have the latest version of Visual Studio SDK installed. After that, perform:

```
pip install dlib
```

I hope this solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

## Update/Install Visual C++

Maybe try installing/updating Visual C++. Because this is necessary for `CMake` to run. You can install it from here, https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&rel=15#

## Installation with Wheel File

Run this:

`pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/da/06/bd3e241c4eb0a662914b3b4875fc52dd176a9db0d4a2c915ac2ad8800e9e/dlib-19.7.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl#md5=b7330a5b2d46420343fbed5df69e6a3f`

## Installation from Internet

1. Install CMake from https://cmake.org/download/
2. Run this,
   `set PATH="%PATH%;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin`
   to add CMake to your path. You can also do this manually by Editing The Environment Variables.
   3)Download the following,
   https://pypi.org/project/dlib/#files.
3. In the specified folder in which you extracted the install files run the following,
   `python setup.py install`.

Answer (score -1):

**Simple and 100% working trick**

(Make sure you install cmake)

My Anaconda python ver : 3.6.8 (64 bit) | OS :Windows 10

```
python -m pip install https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0e/ce/f8a3cff33ac03a8219768f0694c5d703c8e037e6aba2e865f9bae22ed63c/dlib-19.8.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl#sha256=794994fa2c54e7776659fddb148363a5556468a6d5d46be8dad311722d54bfcf
```

[image]

Comment: This is the same exact answer as @Marco D.G. ! whats new here?

Answer (score -3):

**Install dlib in Windows**

download dlib from https://github.com/davisking/dlib.git

download camke from https://cmake.org/download/

Extract cmake and configure it as Environment variable to the extracted path my it was *C:\Users\admin\Downloads\cmake-3.8.1-win32-x86\cmake-3.8.1-win32-x86\bin*

Now extract dlib zip file and go to dlib folder

**Follow this commands**

```
cd dlib/test
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build . --config Release
```

Now go to Release folder which would be at *dlib\test\build\Release* and execute this command
    dtest.exe --runall

This process takes time as cmake compiles all C++ files so stay clam.
Enjoy!!!

Comment: That doesn't install dlib. It just runs the unit tests.