# Install dlib on linux

Tags: dlib

I followed the following steps to install dlib on Linux server:

```
cd dlib 

mkdir build 
cd build 

cmake .. 

cmake --build . --config Release 

make install
```

I got the following error:

```
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector() AttributeError: module 'dlib' has no attribute 'get_frontal_face_detector'
```

Why am I getting this error?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Try out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41912372/dlib-installation-on-windows-10/49538054#49538054

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't bind python API correctly correctly.

```
python setup.py install
```

If you still have error, please post your code, sometime wrong file name also brings error.

Comment: Thank you for your replay. 
Yes I still have some errors as you can see in the below section
when I wrote: make install I got this error(-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libdlib.a
CMake Error at dlib/cmake_install.cmake:41 (file):
file INSTALL cannot copy file
"/home/mylash/.virtualenvs/mylashve/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dlib/build/dlib/libdlib.a"
to "/usr/local/lib/libdlib.a".

And also I got another error after writing: python setup.py install

error: [Errno 38] Function not implemented

Comment: when I wrote: make install I got this error(-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libdlib.a CMake Error at dlib/cmake_install.cmake:41 (file): file INSTALL cannot copy file "/home/mylash/.virtualenvs/mylashve/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dlib/build/dlib/libdlib.a" to "/usr/local/lib/libdlib.a". And also I got another error after writing: python setup.py install error: [Errno 38] Function not implemented

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will be helpful
try his script to reinstall dlib
https://github.com/mhaghighat/dlib_ubuntu_install

after running install script , run setup.py in dlib folder