# Fix CMake errors in installing dlib

Tags: python

i am using python python 3.7.4 amb64 version and i am trying to install dlib package to run an example project.
`pip install dlib` was asking for CMake and i have installed it, also searched for slimier questions and tried all the methods.
[dlib installation on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41912372/dlib-installation-on-windows-10).

still getting this error about C compiler identification is unknown, The CXX compiler identification is unknown, CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:, No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found., No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.

full error goes like this.. any idea why is this happening?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You do not have a C or C++ compiler installed. Did you install visual studio and/or the visual studio build tools?

Comment: @Botje yes i have installed VS latest version and the C,C++ is working properly in it

Comment: do i need to install visual studio build tools separately

Comment: Is your cmake version recent enough to figure out the location of visual studio? Try cmaking a simple C++ project.

Comment: @Eshaka I have a Mac, and had this problem too. All I needed to do is make sure the compiler path was added to PATH. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I was stuck in the frustrating loop of trying to resolve this error for a few days. There are no real answers out there that offer definitive solutions.

The error has got nothing to do with a python version or a cmake version or dlib's installation method(building from source/pip).

I was able to get it resolved by installing the Windows SDK (windows 11 sdk in my case.) [screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSkjd.png)

Also visible in the screenshot, c++ cmake tools for windows is also needed for dlib to compile.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I installed c++ for Visual studio 19 but did not installed the SDK. After installing the SDK then "pip install dlib" works for me.