# Why does "face_recognition" package in seperate thread slow down the UI thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to develop a Pyqt application with face recognition. For the face recognition I use the python package [face_recognition](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition). To keep the UI responsive, I did move a worker with the face recognition to another QThread. However, the UI is still extremly sluggish and lagging.
To check, whether I made a mistake implementing multithreading, I did then replace the face recognition part with a long active waiting loop, like this:

Original face recognition code:

```
face_recognition.face_locations(frame, model="hog")
```

Replaced with active waiting loop:

```
for x in range(59999999):
    pass
```

However in this case, the UI was very responsive. So the relevant part is indeed on another thread. But why is the UI thread lagging when I replace it with the face recognition?

I also did try to set the priority of the UI thread to `QThread.TimeCriticalPriority` (highest) and the priority of the worker to `QThread.IdlePriority` (lowest) but this did not really have an effect.

### EDIT:

Here is a minimal example where I also can observe this behavior. While, the lagging is not as much as in my real application, it's still noticeable here when resizing the window. However, I had to add specific QWidgets like ScrollArea or LineEdit to the UI. Otherwise (e.g. only showing a label) the resizing was smooth.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys, cv2, face_recognition
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, QObject, pyqtSlot

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setup_test_ui()
    self.open_file()
    # QThread.currentThread().setPriority(QThread.TimeCriticalPriority)

  def setup_test_ui(self):
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
    self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
    self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
    self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
    self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.scrollArea)
    self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.lineEdit)
    self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.scrollArea)
    self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

  def open_file(self):
    file_name, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open video", "", "All Files (*);;Movie Files (*.mp4 *.avi)")
    if (file_name):
      self.setup_worker(file_name)

  def setup_worker(self, *args, **kwargs):
    worker = Worker(*args, **kwargs)
    thread = QThread()
    self.worker = (worker, thread)
    worker.moveToThread(thread)
    thread.started.connect(worker.work)

    thread.start()
    # thread.start(QThread.IdlePriority) 

class Worker(QObject):
  def __init__(self, video_source=0, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.vid = cv2.VideoCapture(video_source)
    if not self.vid.isOpened():
      raise ValueError("Unable to open video source", video_source)

  @pyqtSlot()
  def work(self):
    while (True):
      ret, frame = self.vid.read()
      if ret:
        # for x in range(59999999):
        #   pass
        face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(frame, model="hog")

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**Note:** Make sure to install all dependencies: OpenCV, PyQt5, face-recognition. For the last one, you likely have to compile dlib in advance (follow [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49538054/10264920)). Then start the application, use any video file which is used as input for the face_recognition and resize the window (it's lagging a bit for me). Then you can edit the `work` method and use the active waiting loop instead of the face_recognition line. When executing the application now, resizing is very responsive.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: I have a feeling that the blocking line is: ret, frame = self.vid.read() which is probably waiting on some semaphore or using something in the main thread. In yuor place I would try to remove the while(true) and use a timer instead.

Comment: Read up about the GIL and why it makes threads in Python slower than they should be.  https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock

Comment: @MarkRansom This seems like a plausible reason for me. Sadly, this would mean that I can't do anything about it, if I understand it right.

Comment: Well, you could use processes instead of threads, see https://realpython.com/python-gil/#how-to-deal-with-pythons-gil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trying out some things, it seems that the problem was Pythons [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), indeed. With separate processes instead of threads the program works like expected and the UI stays responsive.