# module 'dlib' has no attribute 'get_frontal_face_detector' ERROR

Tags: python, anaconda, face-recognition, dlib

I am trying to use Face_Recognition package on Anaconda, I have installed both dlib and face_recognition library

but when I import face_recognition on my code, I get this error message

```
import dlib
import face_recognition



---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-cc760b0b6613> in <module>()
      1 import dlib
----> 2 import face_recognition

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\face_recognition\__init__.py in <module>()
      5 __version__ = '1.2.3'
      6 
----> 7 from .api import load_image_file, face_locations, batch_face_locations, face_landmarks, face_encodings, compare_faces, face_distance

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\face_recognition\api.py in <module>()
     15 ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True
     16 
---> 17 face_detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
     18 
     19 predictor_68_point_model = face_recognition_models.pose_predictor_model_location()

AttributeError: module 'dlib' has no attribute 'get_frontal_face_detector'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this tutorial:
http://www.programmersought.com/article/7562877819/

> when running the code error: detector =
>   dlib.get_frontal_face_detector() AttributeError: module ' Dlib' has no
>   attribute 'get_frontal_face_detector' or can't open
>   'get_frontal_face_detector' and so on, because you did not download
>   the face database shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks, you need to
>   download it and unzip it and put it in the folder where your code is
>   located. Face Library Download
>   Link:http://dlib.net/files/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2

Comment: I have searched within the installed dlib file and I found that  face database shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks already exists. reinstalling dlib file has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solutions:

1. Reinstall the `dlib` package (`pip3 uninstall dlib`, then `pip3 install dlib`
2. Install `dlib` from source (works for me. Link: http://dlib.net/compile.html)

Comment: Thank you, this solution have worked for me but I had to remove all the dlib files manually and then install it again. but it finally worked!

Comment: "pip3 uninstall dlib" didn't remove all dlib's files from your python modules ?

Answer (score 0):

I followed this thread and worked liked charm.
Click [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49538054/14945612)! checked on Jul 2021
The problem might be with the c++ compiler (Visual Studio) and Cmake installation. Make sure Command prompt is called in the site_packages folder of the virtual environment you want to install dlib. After installation try to call

import dlib

dlib.**version**

if this works then the problem might be a typo. You can confirm whether the function you are calling exists from
[here] (http://dlib.net/python/index.html#dlib.get_frontal_face_detector)!

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that 'dlib' is used as your file name or function name.

Answer (score 0):

Open Anaconda Prompt

First:

```
conda update conda
```

Second:

```
conda update anaconda
```

Third:

```
conda install -c conda-forge dlib
```

Answer (score 0):

First Install Visual Studio and enable [Desktop development with C++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Td5Ok.png) (if the following steps don't work, is possible that you are missing a checkbox, I use VS 2022 and I checked the followings  [checkboxes1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50rrD.png)  [checkboxes2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lv2GH.png)  *I use it in Spanish but it shouldn't be difficult to follow it.

Then follow steps 1 to 3 from https://stackoverflow.com/a/49538054/14945612 (Download and Installation of CMake).

Finally using Python 3.9 (didn't work for me using 3.10 nor 3.11) install the following packages versions (it didn't work for me with newer ones):

> pip install "cmake==3.21.4"

> pip install -v "dlib==19.22.1"

> pip install "face-recognition==1.3.0"

Check that you install them in your correct environment/interpreter.