# Unable to install dlib and face_recognition windows

Tags: python, anaconda, face-recognition, dlib

I have been trying to install dlib and face_recognition in anaconda and haven't been able to do so.
I did install visual studio and cmake and tried it. Still shows the below error

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\gauta\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rdfv1j3q\\dlib_bcbfbd93661e42b88d867f964c16a67b\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\gauta\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rdfv1j3q\\dlib_bcbfbd93661e42b88d867f964c16a67b\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-rratsgq6'
       cwd: C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rdfv1j3q\dlib_bcbfbd93661e42b88d867f964c16a67b\
  Complete output (58 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  package init file 'tools\python\dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  running build_ext
  Building extension for Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
  Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rdfv1j3q\dlib_bcbfbd93661e42b88d867f964c16a67b\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rdfv1j3q\dlib_bcbfbd93661e42b88d867f964c16a67b\build\lib.win-amd64-3.8 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rdfv1j3q\dlib_bcbfbd93661e42b88d867f964c16a67b\build\lib.win-amd64-3.8 -A x64'
  -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (message):
  
  
  
    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  
  
    You must use Visual Studio to build a python extension on windows.  If you
    are getting this error it means you have not installed Visual C++.  Note
    that there are many flavors of Visual Studio, like Visual Studio for C#
    development.  You need to install Visual Studio for C++.
  
  
    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  
  
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rdfv1j3q\dlib_bcbfbd93661e42b88d867f964c16a67b\setup.py", line 222, in <module>
      setup(
    File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 153, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rdfv1j3q\dlib_bcbfbd93661e42b88d867f964c16a67b\setup.py", line 134, in run
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rdfv1j3q\dlib_bcbfbd93661e42b88d867f964c16a67b\setup.py", line 171, in build_extension
      subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
    File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\gauta\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rdfv1j3q\\dlib_bcbfbd93661e42b88d867f964c16a67b\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\gauta\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rdfv1j3q\\dlib_bcbfbd93661e42b88d867f964c16a67b\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.8', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Users\\gauta\\anaconda3\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\gauta\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rdfv1j3q\\dlib_bcbfbd93661e42b88d867f964c16a67b\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.8', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\gauta\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rdfv1j3q\\dlib_bcbfbd93661e42b88d867f964c16a67b\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\gauta\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rdfv1j3q\\dlib_bcbfbd93661e42b88d867f964c16a67b\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ex8cq73s\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\Include\dlib'
         cwd: C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rdfv1j3q\dlib_bcbfbd93661e42b88d867f964c16a67b\
    Complete output (60 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'tools\python\dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Building extension for Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
    Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rdfv1j3q\dlib_bcbfbd93661e42b88d867f964c16a67b\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rdfv1j3q\dlib_bcbfbd93661e42b88d867f964c16a67b\build\lib.win-amd64-3.8 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rdfv1j3q\dlib_bcbfbd93661e42b88d867f964c16a67b\build\lib.win-amd64-3.8 -A x64'
    -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (message):
    
    
    
      !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    
    
      You must use Visual Studio to build a python extension on windows.  If you
      are getting this error it means you have not installed Visual C++.  Note
      that there are many flavors of Visual Studio, like Visual Studio for C#
      development.  You need to install Visual Studio for C++.
    
    
      !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    
    
    
    
    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rdfv1j3q\dlib_bcbfbd93661e42b88d867f964c16a67b\setup.py", line 222, in <module>
        setup(
      File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 153, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rdfv1j3q\dlib_bcbfbd93661e42b88d867f964c16a67b\setup.py", line 134, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rdfv1j3q\dlib_bcbfbd93661e42b88d867f964c16a67b\setup.py", line 171, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
      File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\gauta\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rdfv1j3q\\dlib_bcbfbd93661e42b88d867f964c16a67b\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\gauta\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rdfv1j3q\\dlib_bcbfbd93661e42b88d867f964c16a67b\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.8', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Users\\gauta\\anaconda3\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\gauta\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rdfv1j3q\\dlib_bcbfbd93661e42b88d867f964c16a67b\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.8', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\gauta\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rdfv1j3q\\dlib_bcbfbd93661e42b88d867f964c16a67b\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\gauta\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rdfv1j3q\\dlib_bcbfbd93661e42b88d867f964c16a67b\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ex8cq73s\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\Include\dlib' Check the logs for full command output.

  Using cached dlib-19.22.0.tar.gz (7.4 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for dlib
Failed to build dlib
Installing collected packages: dlib
    Running setup.py install for dlib: started
    Running setup.py install for dlib: finished with status 'error'
Requirement already satisfied: face_recognition in c:\users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.3.0)
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\gauta\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-a5gk8c_j\\dlib_8dc7528b82bb41ef999809e36e6df816\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\gauta\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-a5gk8c_j\\dlib_8dc7528b82bb41ef999809e36e6df816\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-ta0px1h7'
       cwd: C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a5gk8c_j\dlib_8dc7528b82bb41ef999809e36e6df816\
  Complete output (58 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  package init file 'tools\python\dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  running build_ext
  Building extension for Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
  Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a5gk8c_j\dlib_8dc7528b82bb41ef999809e36e6df816\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a5gk8c_j\dlib_8dc7528b82bb41ef999809e36e6df816\build\lib.win-amd64-3.8 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a5gk8c_j\dlib_8dc7528b82bb41ef999809e36e6df816\build\lib.win-amd64-3.8 -A x64'
  -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (message):
  
  
  
    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  
  
    You must use Visual Studio to build a python extension on windows.  If you
    are getting this error it means you have not installed Visual C++.  Note
    that there are many flavors of Visual Studio, like Visual Studio for C#
    development.  You need to install Visual Studio for C++.
  
  
    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  
  
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a5gk8c_j\dlib_8dc7528b82bb41ef999809e36e6df816\setup.py", line 222, in <module>
      setup(
    File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 153, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a5gk8c_j\dlib_8dc7528b82bb41ef999809e36e6df816\setup.py", line 134, in run
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a5gk8c_j\dlib_8dc7528b82bb41ef999809e36e6df816\setup.py", line 171, in build_extension
      subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
    File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\gauta\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-a5gk8c_j\\dlib_8dc7528b82bb41ef999809e36e6df816\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\gauta\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-a5gk8c_j\\dlib_8dc7528b82bb41ef999809e36e6df816\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.8', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Users\\gauta\\anaconda3\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\gauta\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-a5gk8c_j\\dlib_8dc7528b82bb41ef999809e36e6df816\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.8', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\gauta\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-a5gk8c_j\\dlib_8dc7528b82bb41ef999809e36e6df816\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\gauta\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-a5gk8c_j\\dlib_8dc7528b82bb41ef999809e36e6df816\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-9ezrxamk\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\Include\dlib'
         cwd: C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a5gk8c_j\dlib_8dc7528b82bb41ef999809e36e6df816\
    Complete output (60 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'tools\python\dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Building extension for Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
    Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a5gk8c_j\dlib_8dc7528b82bb41ef999809e36e6df816\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a5gk8c_j\dlib_8dc7528b82bb41ef999809e36e6df816\build\lib.win-amd64-3.8 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a5gk8c_j\dlib_8dc7528b82bb41ef999809e36e6df816\build\lib.win-amd64-3.8 -A x64'
    -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (message):
    
    
    
      !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    
    
      You must use Visual Studio to build a python extension on windows.  If you
      are getting this error it means you have not installed Visual C++.  Note
      that there are many flavors of Visual Studio, like Visual Studio for C#
      development.  You need to install Visual Studio for C++.
    
    
      !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    
    
    
    
    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a5gk8c_j\dlib_8dc7528b82bb41ef999809e36e6df816\setup.py", line 222, in <module>
        setup(
      File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 153, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a5gk8c_j\dlib_8dc7528b82bb41ef999809e36e6df816\setup.py", line 134, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a5gk8c_j\dlib_8dc7528b82bb41ef999809e36e6df816\setup.py", line 171, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
      File "C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\gauta\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-a5gk8c_j\\dlib_8dc7528b82bb41ef999809e36e6df816\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\gauta\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-a5gk8c_j\\dlib_8dc7528b82bb41ef999809e36e6df816\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.8', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Users\\gauta\\anaconda3\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\gauta\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-a5gk8c_j\\dlib_8dc7528b82bb41ef999809e36e6df816\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.8', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\gauta\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-a5gk8c_j\\dlib_8dc7528b82bb41ef999809e36e6df816\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\gauta\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-a5gk8c_j\\dlib_8dc7528b82bb41ef999809e36e6df816\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-9ezrxamk\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\Include\dlib' Check the logs for full command output.
```

What am i missing here?? I have looked at all the solutions from different sources.

1. Installe CMake and looked for the path variable and it exists.
2. Installed Visual Studio Build Tools and still shows as not exists as per the above error.

Can anyone suggest me what is wrong here??

Answer (score 0):

I can see from you PATH that you have conda. You can use precompile versions from conda-forge channel.

```sh
# create environment with any name 
# and install dlib and face_recognition from conda-forge channel 

conda create --name faces python=3.7 dlib face_recognition --channel conda-forge
```

To use, activate the environment and use your package

```sh
conda activate faces
python -c "import face_recognition"
```

This will most lively not make use of your GPU's if you have them. To do so, we have to build dlib from source matching your specific GPU settings. That needs more work. See another SO forum [dlib installation on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41912372/dlib-installation-on-windows-10)

Comment: So when i tried this i am getting a new error
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda create --name faces python=3.7 dlib face_recognition --channel conda-forge
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

NotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to a required path.
  path: C:\Users\gauta\anaconda3\pkgs\cache\f7597cf7.json

Comment: This is because you are in `C:\WINDOWS\system32>` You need administrator power to install anything in that folder. Try Documents or any other place

Comment: I did. Changed it to other folders. Still gives the same issue.

Comment: What folder are you in? Can you try Documents folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way download the zip file  https://github.com/CodeEZ-Dev/face-recognition_dlib_library here and extract it to C:\Users<User name> location. Then open your command prompt and run the wheel `pip install dlib-19.19.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl` if you are using python version 3.8.This will get dlib installed and it will not throw errors when installing face_recognition afterwards.