# Can't install face_recognition

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install face_recognition with `pip install face_recognition` but any time I do that it gives me this output: https://pastebin.com/LJ3XRdSq
Does anyone know a fix for this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. Relevant code must be shared _here_ as a [mre]. Please [edit] your question and add the code directly to your question.

Comment: try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70001837/problem-in-installing-python-library-face-recognition-on-windows-10-11/70044454#70044454)
I used this method do install it on my laptop

Answer (score 1):

You have to install `cmake` and `dlib`:

On the [`face_recognition` github page](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition#installation):

> Installing on Mac or Linux
> First, make sure you have `dlib` already installed with Python bindings.
> Then, make sure you have cmake installed:

So run these:

```
pip install cmake
```

```
pip install dlib
```

Before you install `face_recognition`:

```
pip install face_recognition
```

If you're getting an error while installing `dlib` look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49538054/14771613).
Also watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jjRFCTmK2SY

Comment: This is what I get when I try and do that https://pastebin.com/U1Y81yDk

Comment: I edited my answer. Take a look at it.

Comment: It says that ```git``` is not a recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: You'll need to install `git` first: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git

Comment: I did your method and got this https://pastebin.com/bmXXg36e

I did what the video said but this is what I got when trying to install that file ```C:\Users\Kevin Gree>pip install dlib-19.19.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
WARNING: Requirement 'dlib-19.19.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
ERROR: dlib-19.19.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.```

Comment: I am running windows 10, and I put the file in my Documents

Comment: Found a good answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49538054/14771613

Comment: I keep getting ```ERROR: dlib-19.7.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.``` when trying to install .whl files

Comment: See the second half of the answer I sent in the comments

Comment: I followed the fix in the link, but got this ```C:\Users\Kevin Gree>python setup.py install
python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory```