# Yet Another DLIB installation problem despite CMake installed

Tags: python, cmake, pip, face-recognition, dlib

I have `CMake` tool installed using Visual STudio Build tools 2019. I have rechecked my ENV variables multiple times.

I have tried installation using the `Source`. I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41912372/dlib-installation-on-windows-10) and all the other discussions as well.

Here is the detailed error

```
running install
C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\drowsiness-detection\envt\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  warnings.warn(
C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\drowsiness-detection\envt\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py:160: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  warnings.warn(
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing tools/python\dlib.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to tools/python\dlib.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to tools/python\dlib.egg-info\top_level.txt
package init file 'tools\python\dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
reading manifest file 'tools/python\dlib.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
no previously-included directories found matching 'tools\python\build*'
no previously-included directories found matching 'dlib\cmake_utils\*\build*'
no previously-included directories found matching 'dlib\test'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
writing manifest file 'tools/python\dlib.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
C:\Users\asus\Downloads\dlib-19.23.0\dlib-19.23.0\setup.py:129: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
  if LooseVersion(cmake_version) < '3.1.0':
Building extension for Python 3.10.2 (tags/v3.10.2:a58ebcc, Jan 17 2022, 14:12:15) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\asus\Downloads\dlib-19.23.0\dlib-19.23.0\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\asus\Downloads\dlib-19.23.0\dlib-19.23.0\build\lib
.win-amd64-3.10 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\drowsiness-detection\envt\Scripts\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\asus\Downloads\dlib-19.23.0\dlib-19.23.0\build\lib.win-amd64-3.10 -A x64'
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.17763.0 to target Windows 10.0.22000.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (project):
  Failed to run MSBuild command:

    C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe

  to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

    Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.11.2+f32259642 for .NET Framework
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

    Build started 27-Feb-22 6:58:45 PM.
    Project "C:\Users\asus\Downloads\dlib-19.23.0\dlib-19.23.0\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\CMakeFiles\3.18.4\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.Cpp.WindowsSDK.targets(46,5): error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 10.0.17763.0
 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution". [C:\Users\asus\Downloads\dlib-19.23.0\dlib-19.23.0\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\CMakeFiles\3.18.4\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]
    Done Building Project "C:\Users\asus\Downloads\dlib-19.23.0\dlib-19.23.0\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\CMakeFiles\3.18.4\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.    

    Build FAILED.

    "C:\Users\asus\Downloads\dlib-19.23.0\dlib-19.23.0\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\CMakeFiles\3.18.4\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
    (_CheckWindowsSDKInstalled target) ->
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.Cpp.WindowsSDK.targets(46,5): error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 10.0.17763
.0 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution". [C:\Users\asus\Downloads\dlib-19.23.0\dlib-19.23.0\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\CMakeFiles\3.18.4\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]

        0 Warning(s)
        1 Error(s)

    Time Elapsed 00:00:00.21


  Exit code: 1



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/asus/Downloads/dlib-19.23.0/dlib-19.23.0/build/temp.win-amd64-3.10/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\asus\Downloads\dlib-19.23.0\dlib-19.23.0\setup.py", line 222, in <module>
    setup(
  File "C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\drowsiness-detection\envt\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 155, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\drowsiness-detection\envt\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    return run_commands(dist)
  File "C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\drowsiness-detection\envt\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 163, in run_commands
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\drowsiness-detection\envt\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\drowsiness-detection\envt\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\drowsiness-detection\envt\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 74, in run
    self.do_egg_install()
  File "C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\drowsiness-detection\envt\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 116, in do_egg_install
    self.run_command('bdist_egg')
  File "C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\drowsiness-detection\envt\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "C:\Users\asus\Downloads\dlib-19.23.0\dlib-19.23.0\setup.py", line 171, in build_extension
    subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 369, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\asus\\Downloads\\dlib-19.23.0\\dlib-19.23.0\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\asus\\Downloads\\dlib-19.23.0\\dlib-19.23.0\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.10', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Users\\asus\\PycharmProjects\\drowsiness-detection\\envt\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\asus\\Downloads\\dlib-19.23.0\\dlib-19.23.0\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.10', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I am not using `Anacodna` and I am on Windows 10 platform. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `Windows SDK version 10.0.17763.0` installed? It should look something like this screenshot:[image]

Comment: I cant add images in comments. So this shall help https://ibb.co/pbjsm1P

Comment: @Astrian According to your image, you have SDK `19041` installed, but according to the error from your original post you need to have `17763` installed.