# Error in installing dlib library in python3.11

Tags: python, cmake, dlib

I am facing issue installing dlib on windows 10
Edition Windows 10 Home Single Language
Version 22H2
Installed on    ‎13-‎07-‎2022
OS build    19045.2251
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4180.0

I have cmake installed
➜ cmake --version
cmake version 3.24.0-rc3

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware

I have python 3.11 installed
➜ py --version
Python 3.11.0

I have tried to install dlib using pip
The error I recieved have been uploaded to pastebin

```
File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 151, in call_command
    self.run_command(cmdname)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 319, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
    super().run_command(command)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 987, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install_lib.py", line 11, in run
    self.build()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\install_lib.py", line 112, in build
    self.run_command('build_ext')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 319, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
    super().run_command(command)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 987, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\alent\Downloads\dlib-19.24\setup.py", line 134, in run
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "C:\Users\alent\Downloads\dlib-19.24\setup.py", line 174, in build_extension
    subprocess.check_call(cmake_build, cwd=build_folder)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 413, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--build', '.', '--config', 'Release', '--', '/m']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

https://pastebin.com/8N5kb75D

Then I tried building it from source
So I downloaded the latest release from https://github.com/davisking/dlib/releases/tag/v19.24
The error I recied have been uploaded to pastebin
https://pastebin.com/YjiVTMEp

Please help me.
Thank you for looking into this.

When I try to build it from source, I get https://pastebin.com/YjiVTMEp
When I try to install using pip, I get https://pastebin.com/8N5kb75D

Answer (score 7):

Yes. I made it successful using python3.11
All you need to do is

1. Clone the repo using
   `git clone https://github.com/davisking/dlib`
2. Get inside the directory in cmd using
   `cd dlib`
3. Make sure you have visual studio desktop development with c++
   [image: Heres the image]
4. Install cmake from https://cmake.org/download/
5. Using pip to install cmake
   `py -m pip install cmake`
6. Then try installing dlib by
   `py setup.py install`

If this worked please upvote my solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install it using github but it didn't worked well, then I was facing problems with dlib and the face-recognition module.

So I tried the following and worked for me:

First Install Visual Studio and enable [Desktop development with C++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Td5Ok.png) (if the following steps don't work, is possible that you are missing a checkbox, I use VS 2022 and I checked the followings  [checkboxes1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50rrD.png)  [checkboxes2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lv2GH.png) *I use it in Spanish but it shouldn't be difficult to follow it.

Then follow steps 1 to 3 from https://stackoverflow.com/a/49538054/14945612 (Download and Installation of CMake).

Finally using Python 3.9 (didn't work for me using 3.10 nor 3.11) install the following packages versions (it didn't work for me with newer ones):

> pip install "cmake==3.21.4"

> pip install -v "dlib==19.22.1"

> pip install "face-recognition==1.3.0"

Check that you install them in your correct environment/interpreter. In my case I created a new conda environment with Python 3.9 and then use this new environment as my PyCharm Interpreter. That way I downgrade my Python.

Answer (score 0):

dlib is not install in python 3.11 version. Downgrade your python version in Anaconda prompt

```
conda install python=3.9
```

And install dlib. Download dlib from *https://pypi.org/simple/dlib/* and install it

```
!pip install "C:\Users\Downloads\dlib-19.22.99-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl"
```