# Dlib ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _dlib_pybind11: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, importerror, dllimport, dlib

When trying to use `dlib` this message is showing:

```
import dlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\NEERAJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\dlib\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from _dlib_pybind11 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _dlib_pybind11: The specified module could not be found.`
```

The file `_dlib_pybind11` is present but Python is still not able to use it.

What should I do?

I tried changing the versions of `dlib` and uninstalling and reinstalling but it still does not work.

Comment: How exactly did you install it? Which OS are you on? Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41912372/dlib-installation-on-windows-10?